# Is there a way to programmatically determine the optimal Bing Maps Zoom Level based on an array of GPS Coordinates?

Tags: gps, coordinates, zooming, bing-maps, coordinate-transformation

When programmatically adding an array of GPS Coordinates to a Bing Map, I want to set the Zoom level to the optimal - to show every pushpin/location, but "just barely."

I imagine a way to do this would be to identify the furthest points in the cardinal directions found within the array of coordinates, and then calculate how many miles you need to display both east-to-west and north-to-south.

For example, let's say the furthest north and furthest south locations are determined to be forty miles distant from each other, and the furthest east and furthest west locations are determined to be sixty miles apart from each other. Is there a rule of thumb/calculation/algorithm that would determine what the most "zoomed-in" level would be that would display all of the locations/coordinates, with the "outliers" being as close to the edge of the displayed portion of the map as possible?

Comment: I think yes. They all use Web Mercator, you may check https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels . Not sure that zoom levels are 1 to 1, but I think there is a clear relation (because of design of web mercator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a map view with a bounding box, which will automatically determine the zoom level. See the example here
https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/setmapviewoptions
using the Bounds property as documented here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-api/viewoptions-object