# Is there a way to programmatically determine the GPS Coordinate which should serve as the Center of a Bing Map?

Tags: c#, uwp, gps, bing-maps, centering

This is kind of similar/related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128312/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-determine-the-optimal-bing-maps-zoom-level-ba?noredirect=1#comment115141756_65128312), but different enough to warrant a separate question.

When an array of GPS Coordinates are programmatically added to a Bing Map, I want to set the center of the map to the midpoint between all of the GPS coordinates in the array. For example, if I wanted to show Hannibal, Independence, Columbia, Jefferson City, and St. Louis (all in Missouri), the center should be around Columbia.

[image]

I imagine a way to do this might be to add all the latitudes and divide by the number of locations being marked (5 in the above case), and add all the longitudes and divide by that number also. The two averages could serve as the Center.

Is that a sensible way to compute the center coordinate, or is there a better way?

I want to do this in the code-behind (in C#).

### UPDATE

Here's my idea of what the (pseudo)code might be:

```
int locationCount = GetNumberOfLocationsOnMap(currentMap);
double totalLatitude = GetTotalLatitudesOfLocationsOnMap(currentMap);
double totalLongitude = GetTotalLongitudesOfLocationsOnMap(currentMap);
double avgLatitude = totalLatitude div locationCount;
double avgLongitude = totalLongitude div locationCount;
map.Center = avgLatitude, avgLongitude;
```

If there's a simpler and/or better way, I'd like to know it.

### UPDATE 2

This works, with just one location (based on Duncan Lawler's answer and link):

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    . . .
    SetInitialScene();
}

private async void SetInitialScene()
{
    // Set it to Monterey, California
    BasicGeoposition location = new BasicGeoposition();
    location.Latitude = 36.6002; 
    location.Longitude = -121.8947; 
    Geopoint geop = new Geopoint(location);
    await map.TrySetSceneAsync(MapScene.CreateFromLocation(geop));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the UWP map control, there's a built in method to do this for you.
Just call
MapControl.TrySetSceneAsync(MapScene.CreateFromLocations(yourListOfPointsHere));
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapscene.createfromlocations
It will calculate the right view and move the map there. If you need to know the center, you can just query the Center property after the SetScene call completes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the center of bounding box of the coordinates will work better for this task, because in this case points can fit the screen at the higher zoom level.

```
var latitudes = currentMap.locations.Select(location => location.latitude);
var longitudes = currentMap.locations.Select(location => location.longitude);
centerLatitude = (latitudes.Min() + latitudes.Max()) / 2.0;
centerLongitude = (longitudes.Min() + longitudes.Max()) / 2.0;
map.Center = centerLatitude, centerLongitude;
```

However be careful with coordinates that are near poles or near 180 longitude, as minimum and maximum will not provide a valid bounding box. The same problem exists when you compute mean values too.

Comment: Yes, depending on your use case grabbing the center of the bounding box will be better than the approach in the question. The approach in the question will give you a weighted average of positions, so if you have a lot of points in the city and a few outlying points it will center on the city.

Comment: One other thing to be aware of is depending on your display projection, the center of a lat/long bounding box will not be the center of the display area. The commonly used web mercator projection for example is non-linear in latitude so the center of the display is not the midpoint between the top and bottom latitudes.

Comment: @DuncanLawler Good point! In that case it would be better to convert latitude and longitude to Mercator projection and only then compute the bounding box

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "center". As mentioned by others, Lat and Lon are spherical references but maps usually are not. Test for the former would be that two points 80deg N Lat and 0 and 180 deg Lon should be the north pole (90 Lat). But this is probably not what you're after.

Comment: That doesn't compile for me. My map's name is simply "map" and there is no "locations" member. Maybe because my app is a UWP?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your map display all your GPS points, you will need a zoom level to go with the center. The zoom level is directly related to the maps width and height. Here is a code block from an old code sample of mine:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the best map view for a list of locations for a map
/// </summary>
/// <param name="locations">List of location objects</param>
/// <param name="mapWidth">Map width in pixels</param>
/// <param name="mapHeight">Map height in pixels</param>
/// <param name="buffer">Width in pixels to use to create a buffer around the map. This is to keep pushpins from being cut off on the edge</param>
public static MapViewSpecification BestMapView(IList<Location> locations, double mapWidth, double mapHeight, int buffer, out double centerLat, double centerLon, out double zoomLevel )
{
    double zoomLevel = 0;

    double maxLat = -85;
    double minLat = 85;
    double maxLon = -180;
    double minLon = 180;

    //calculate bounding rectangle
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.Count; i++)
    {
        if (locations[i].Latitude > maxLat)
        {
            maxLat = locations[i].Latitude;
        }

        if (locations[i].Latitude < minLat)
        {
            minLat = locations[i].Latitude;
        }

        if (locations[i].Longitude > maxLon)
        {
            maxLon = locations[i].Longitude;
        }

        if (locations[i].Longitude < minLon)
        {
            minLon = locations[i].Longitude;
        }
    }

    centerLat = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
    centerLon = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;

    double zoom1=0, zoom2=0;

    //Determine the best zoom level based on the map scale and bounding coordinate information
    if (maxLon != minLon && maxLat != minLat)
    {
        //best zoom level based on map width
        zoom1 = Math.Log(360.0 / 256.0 * (mapWidth – 2*buffer) / (maxLon – minLon)) / Math.Log(2);
        //best zoom level based on map height
        zoom2 = Math.Log(180.0 / 256.0 * (mapHeight – 2*buffer) / (maxLat – minLat)) / Math.Log(2);
    }

    //use the most zoomed out of the two zoom levels
    zoomLevel = (zoom1 < zoom2) ? zoom1 : zoom2;
}
```

Comment: Once centerLat and centerLon are arrived at, how is map.Center assigned? (assuming "map" is the name of the Bing Map). Like so: Location center;
center.latitude = centerLat;
center.longitude = centerLon;
map.SetView(center, zoomLevel); ?